# Match and Replace first <p> paragraph contents of output?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have content that is being outputted via Wordpress, and it wraps paragraph `<p>` tags around the content. I need to remove the content within the first `<p></p>` .. How can I do this?

For example, output is:

```
<p>Posted by Bob</p>
<p>This is the content here</p>
<p>This is the second paragraph</p>
```

I'd like to remove the line `<p>Posted by Bob</p>` and leave the rest.

Comment: Are you trying to replace the content or remove the whole tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, [you should not parse HTML with regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454).

In this case, a regex solution might work fine though:

```
$str = preg_replace('~<p>.*?</p>~s', '', $str, 1);
```

The important things are

- the `?` which makes the `.*` ungreedy (so that it stop as soon as possible and does not continue until the very last `</p>`
- the modifier `s` so that `.` is able to match new-lines
- the limit `1` so that only the first match is removed

If you only want to remove the contents of the tag (so if you want to keep an empty paragraph), simply use `<p></p>` as the replacement string.

However, as I said this is still not a perfect solution. Think about `<p>` tags in comments, or `<p>` tags that have attributes or even invalid HTML. PHP comes with a [DOM parser](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php). If you can use 3rd-party libraries there is also [this one](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net), which is quite convenient to use and makes the problem almost trivial:

```
require "simple_html_dom.php";

$html = new simple_html_dom($input);
$html->load($input);

$html->find('p', 0)->outertext = "";

$output = $html->save();
```

Equally if you just want to empty the tag, but keep it, replace `outertext` with `innertext`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to jQuery you could use the following:

```
$("p:first-child").text("Hello World!");
```

To include jQuery in WordPress add the following in your `<head></head>`:

```
<?php wp_enqueue_script("jquery"); ?>
<?php wp_head(); ?>
```

This includes jQuery in a safe way and prevents any conflicts with other instances of jQuery or other libraries.